# MGS 2/MGS 3 vs Substance/Subsistence

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

For both MGS 2 and MGS 3, what changed between their original and their updated releases, anything from major to minor?

Comment: I probably would have split them up across seperate questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### MGS 2: Substance

- Provides a VR training mode offering hundreds of extra missions outside the main story, such as target practice, enemy elimination, bomb disposal, and more. These missions are playable as Raiden or Snake.
- Tells the "*Snake Tales*", which are 5 non-canonical story missions featuring Snake as main the character.
- For the PS2 as an exclusive mission, a demo of Evolution Skating was released where you could play as Snake or Raiden and skate throughout the Big Shell.

---

#### MGS 3: Subsistence

- Ships with a playable version of ***Metal Gear*** and ***Metal Gear 2: Solid Snake*** (not to be confused with *Metal Gear Solid*), accessible from the title screen.
- Replaces the over-head camera known from MGS 1 and MGS 2 by a freely controllable 3D camera as seen in most modern 3D games.
- Introduces the online component known as ***Metal Gear Online***. Servers have long since been shut down, and MGO has not been released in the HD remakes.
- Includes downloadable camouflages and face paints, as well as a stage called "Snake vs. Monkey" previously exclusive to the European version of the game.
- Adds the *European Extreme* difficulty level, which is just like the *Extreme* difficulty level, only it's Game Over if you get spotted.
- Features parody cut scenes and trailers.
- Supports connectivity with ***Metal Gear Acid 2***.

Comment: Nice. But some of the features you list under 3 is included in the standard version.

Comment: Also: 
MGS2S: The Thermal Goggles, Character display sunglasses every other playthrough, and the European Extreme Dificulty (like in MGS3)
MGS3: The Konami code entry during the Konamy intro of the game doesn't make the "item" sound like in Snake Eater, and "I Like MGS3" selection upon new game